# Filling the unused space with ground plane in mixed signal pcb

Tags: pcb, signal, design, ground

I'm designing a 4-layer pcb which consists of a GSM module, GPS module, a microcontroller (SAM4S) and a proper dc to dc buck converter.

The traces of the antennas are extremely short, fewer than 5mm long.

And the highest speed of signals is the SPI which I chose for external nor flash and/or a micro sdcard communication.

There are also few analog signals for monitoring very low frequencies (100 Hz in worst case).

I was thinking if it's a good idea to fill every unused space with ground plane stitching with vias (as if it's manufactured in cnc). I will not let any dead copper though.

Will this cause any problem in signal integrity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the datasheets I saw had a recommendation, how to use the ground planes around the RF IC.

- most of the chip/pcb antenna designs recommended no filling around the RF lines, similar to this one. Possible reasons: reduce parasitics, field-shaping, etc. Notice the stitching vias at the edge of the polygons. [image source](https://blog.adafruit.com/2016/05/11/antenna-design-and-rf-layout-guidelines-white-paper-from-cypresssemi-radio/)

[image]

- I saw some designs with external antennas, that used filling around the RF line. Here you have to take care of the characteristic impedance of your line. If your RF line is a microstrip on the surface layer, then your refence is usually one of the internal layers. Thus you have to take care, that the filling on the outer layer is coupled much less to your signal, than the internal layers. The recommendations I've read mention a clearance around 3-4x the distance to the reference plane. [image source](http://iot-bits.com/simple-rf-pcb-layout-tips-tricks/)

[image]

So my recommendation is:

- check your datasheet recommendation or app. notes of the supplier
- if there is nothing regarding this, I would leave the area around the antenna empty (no components, no copper, nothing at all), but I would separate the non-rf part with a filling + stitching vias, in order to make wave propagation inside the pcb impossible + reduce EM emission of the DC/DC

PS: regarding digital signals - it is not the SPI frequency that matters regarding signal integrity, but the rise and fall times of those signals. Rule of thumb: if your track is longer than 1/10-th of the way the signal travels during the rise/fall time, you might get reflection issues.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that, unless you know exactly what for. Creating unexpected capacitance is always a bad idea, as all kinds of AC stuff (mainly from switching devices, but not only) will travel the most unexpected ways.

Actually what you should do is to channel ac stuff exactly the way you want.

Comment: I thought that ground was good practice, in general

Comment: In some cases it is. If you have to cover something, if you need predictable z0. but not just pour copper and hope everything will be fine.

Comment: You can have predictable Z0 with ground poured, you just have to be extra careful about it.

Comment: Not just copper, but copper connected to ground with vias.

Comment: That's what i said.. But when you don't need it- it's better not to pour ground. Because then everything below it will be capacitively coupled

Comment: Layers below that ground pour is power planes, there's no signal traces there. But I will consider your advice very carefully.

Comment: How can I predict if this ground pour would be harmless or not?

Comment: I've rescued numerous PCBs from FCC susceptibility test failures after the fact, by examining the Ground pours and then intentionally stitching the GND pours together with heavy traces and multiple vias. If some components needed to be moved slightly to allow heavy stitching traces, then components were moved. And in some cases, where failure was in the 400-600MHz region, we'd insert 10Kohm resistors into digital lines to break up resonant quarter-wave structures and prevent  high energy injection into vulnerable ICs on either end of 6" traces.

Comment: After a few iterations of these fail-diagnose-stitchtogether cycles, the junior staffers got together and discussed the general methods being used (given the use of total GND plane surfaces was not--for cost reasons--allowed), and examples collected into photocopied working documents; the PCB layout jocks happily put the methods into practice, and FCC (and European) susceptility failures ceased.

Comment: I found another topic similar with mine. I see positive answers there.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/186351/for-a-4-layers-pcb-with-ground-plane-covering-with-ground-polygon-on-layer-1?rq=1

Comment: You can always go ahead and try. I am speaking out of my experience. The specific one: parasitic capacity may surprise, and the general one: do only things you know why are you doing them.

Comment: Wouldn't parasitic capacitance appear only in cases in which ground pour has too little clearance?

Comment: No, no. It's always there. The pour has currents on it, and it has voltage drop therefore, and so on. Many weird things can happen. I saw it last week. It wasn't even a ground pour on the PCB, it was an aluminum case fem mm above. Yet it created enough capacitance to inject AC into a high resistance line.

Comment: How can I eliminate those currents?

Comment: Don't allow them :) channel them through low impedance to where they are allowed. Create high impedance (including cuts in power planes) where they are not allowed. It's not simple enough for just one post on a forum.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74672/discussion-between-mrbit-and-gregory-kornblum).